# How do I AJAX in an XML file and parse the values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ajax

I have the following AJAX and XML code. You can see the values that I am trying to set. I'm just not sure how to go about parsing the XML file to set these variables.

**AJAX code:**

```
$.ajax({
          url: 'PATH TO XML',
          dataType: ($.browser.msie) ? "text" : "xml",
          success: function(data) {
                        var context = default;
                        if ( ... ) {
                           context = not-default;
                        }
                    }
```

**XML code:**

```
<messages>
 <message id="id1" context="default">
      <content>

            <p>Default HTML</p>


      </content>
 </message>
 <message id="id2" context="not-default">
      <content>

        <p>Not Default HTML</p>

      </content>
</message>
</messages>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty simple:

```
$(yourXmlFileContents);
```

From here, just use the [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method to select elements:

```
$(yourXmlFileContents).find('foo[context=bar]');
```

**NOTE:** If you supply the document's contents as a *string* jQuery won't interpret it as XML, but as HTML instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't realize that a .find was all that was needed! And thanks for the example Faith!!

Comment: Note that jQuery's `$()` function does not parse XML if the value supplied is a string. It assumes the string is HTML, and assigns the string as the `innerHTML` property of an HTML DOM element, which does not generally work for XML. If the value supplied is an XML document, everything's fine.

Answer (score 0):

[See this example](http://www.fatihacet.com/lab/xml):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "xml",
        url: "XMLFile.xml",
        success: function (xml) {
            $(xml).find('type').each(function () { // find all "type" tag in XML
                if ($(this).text() == 'administrative_area_level_3') { // in here $(this) is our "type" tag
                    var result = $(this).parent().find('long_name').text(); // get result
                    $('#result').html('The Result is: ' + result) // write result
                }
            })
        }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set the `dataType` as "xml", the value supplied to your `success` function will be an XML document object and passing it to the main jQuery function will do what you want. If you have XML as a string instead, you need to pass it jQuery's `parseXML()` method (new in version 1.5):

```
var xmlStr = "<foo>bar</foo>";
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xmlStr);
$xml = $(xmlDoc);
alert($xml.find("foo").text()); // Alerts "bar"
```